# MVC Unobtrusive Validation. How to display validation message inner invalid element?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation

How to display validation message inner invalid element with MVC Unobtrusive validation? Additionally, when focused on the invalid element should show a value that the user entered.

Comment: Can you explain what you want by providing an example? Your question is not clear. Typically, you have a `Html.ValidationMessageFor(input => Model.input)` which outputs the validation message for the specific input and the input is on a form which is visible so the current value is already present.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases unobtrusive validation  is very simple using the ValidationMessageFor helper :

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Item.Title)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Item.Title)
```

However note that there is a known bug in MVC which will not display the validation for nested model properties displayed using a TextArea, so

```
  @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Item.Title)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Item.Title)
```

Will not work (in most circumstances I tested anyway). Ref is http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8576